# how to create two onactivityresult for two different class

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am having two different classes. One class is for adding image and uploading it to server and another class for editing the saved image with new image. So for getting image from sdcard, in add class I am using `startactivityforresult` and `onactivityresult`. Same thing I am trying to use in edit class because in this class im having an `ImageView` where new image is added but it is not allowing me to create `onactivityresult` in edit class. Saying error as onactivityresult is already defined. If someone knows please help me.

**code:**

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
           bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            imageToUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: post your source code please and error you are facing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xsspjfft/  error: Error:(341, 20) error: method onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) is already defined in class EditCont

Comment: show me code in ur edit activity

Comment: You can may be having different `resultCodes` or better yet, use `requestCodes`

Comment: You need to define some integer values for this and pass it from startActivityResult so when you receive result at onActivityResult you can check that value and do operation accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
startActivityForResult (intent, int requestCode);
```

Then in `onActivityResult` you can use switch case using requestCode.
Like:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
     switch(requestCode) {
           //Have your cases here
           }
}
```